# Share a Concurrent Hashmap Between Multiple Apache Storm Bolt Tasks

Tags: java, concurrency, apache-storm

I have a storm bolt which writes keys and values to a hashmap from certain tuples and reads values from the hashmap using keys stored in others. It works fine when the number of tasks is set to one but as soon as I increase this number the keys begin to return null values when they shouldnt. I assume this is because each bolt task is creating its own instance of the hashmap so data isnt shared. How do I get all bolt tasks to share a single Hashmap?

I am currently creating the hashmap in the prepare method like so:

```
protected Map<String, JsonObject> hashMap;

@Override
public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector)
{
    _collector = collector;
    hashMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<String, JsonObject>());

}
```

I have also tried defining the hashmap at the topology level and giving it to my bolt as a variable but this did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task can be deployed to different workers, (ie, different machines) and thus, you cannot share anything in-memory between tasks.

Tasks as "independent units of work" an must solely depend on their input.

Comment: Ive managed to get the hashmap shared over a single worker by using a static hashmap but you are correct, I cannot produce this functionality across multiple workers. Do you know of anyway I could guarentee "sets" of tuples to only be sent to specific worker instances?

Comment: You can use `.fieldGrouping()`

Comment: Thats what Ive ended up doing. as an aside, do you know how storm manages to maintain the field grouping accross different workers. Does it constantly pass tuples between workers?

Comment: Yes. If you use fieldsGrouping() record will be repartitioned via network such that they go to the right one -- any distributed system needs to do this (it's not specific to Storm)